# Is it technically ok to hand edit iOS storyboard files?

Tags: ios, xml, user-interface

I have developed for Android and starting iOS development. For Android, I used both drag-and-drop UI elements and manually hand-editing the xml file to build up UI. Hand-editing xml view files provides me the precision I want. But that does not mean, I just used raw XML and never looked at the visual UI builder. In iOS world, the UI commonly resided in a storyboard file, which is actually an xml file. I want to follow the same approach I followed in Android, start with drag-and-drop, then hand edit the file to make things precise. My question is, is there any technical problem in this approach? Can hand editing break the app? I am asking this because nobody is doing it this way.

I want to go with this approach if it does not potentially break things, even if it is not common or standard practice. And the reason I don't want to do this programmatically is, then I have to maintain a mental model of the UI in my mind, as I cannot see it before building and running in simulator/device. I am not interested in modifying identifiers as they are referenced throughout the project and not easy to refactor. I am more interested in changing values of different attributes. It's more like tweaking rather than editing.

Comment: I would say no... a new version could come out and break your world... I would do basic stuff in storyboard and edit with code if you need to tweak things at a level that the gui doesn't support.

Comment: Setting constants is fine. Setting up anything new would take you so much longer that nothing could be worth it. Though everything in the utility pane has given me all the precision I need and I've done some pretty complicated UIs in storyboards.

Answer (score 3):

DON'T edit the storyboard files by hand!
You're gonna have a bad time! I guarantee!

I know it's common to do so in Android Studio but in iOS you are gonna have some really big troubles with the identifiers even though the Code is generated in readable XML.

Comment: If I don't touch the identifiers?

Comment: Apples storyboard structure isn't so easy to read. When we have mergeconflicts, we prefer to solve them in a pair programming session and only with xcode's gui-editor. I mean, when it's a one-line conflict, that one is easy, but copy-pasting and moving code in the structur can lead to a few hours extra work. If you than have a git system, you are gonna be one lucky guy!

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative you might consider is MarkupKit:

https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit

It allows you to build native iOS apps using a human-readable XML markup language, similar to Android. It doesn't support a GUI builder, though - you'd need to create your initial markup by hand.